# Two arrays one with time in, another with time out of something

Tags: arrays, algorithm, object, max, indices

Lets say we have 2 arrays, one of them (i.e. A) contains the time an object **i** will come into a room, and the other (i.e. B) contains the time **i** will leave. Neither of these are in any way sorted and their contents are **Real numbers**.

For example, object 3 has: A[3]=0.785 and B[3]=4.829.

How would you in **O(nlogn)** find the max objects in the room at any given time t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

- initialize number of objects as zero
- sort both arrays
- while there are elements left in either array

  - determine which array's first value is smaller
  - if the first value in "enter" is smaller, increment number of objects and pop that value
  - if the first value in "leave" is smaller, decrement number of objects and pop that value
  - check whether you found a new maximum number of objects

If you can not "pop" elements from the arrays, you can use two index variables instead; also, you will have to add cases for when one of the arrays is already empty.

Sorting has O(nlogn), and the following loop has O(2*n), thus O(nlogn) in total.

Answer (score 1):

Get all times from both arrays and make pairs `{time from A or from B; f = +1 for A/ -1 for B}`

Sort array of all pairs by time key (in case of tie +1 goes before -1)

Make `count = 0`

Traverse array of pairs, adding `f` value to `count`.

Max value of `count` is " the max objects in the room"

Example:

```
  A = [2, 5], B = [7, 9]
  pairs = (2,1),(5,1),(7,-1),(9,-1)
  count = 1, 2, 1, 0 
  maxcount=2 at interval 5..7
```

Comment: @tobias_k There are 2*n pairs (time moments), sorting O(nlogn). Traversing O(n). Why quadratic?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what those pairs are. Makes sense, and is in fact simpler than my approach.